# Problems retrieving data from controller using Ember.js 2.3.0

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to learn ember following this course and I have the following controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  title:'My Blog Post',
  body:'Body of the post',
  authors:['Author1', 'Author2', 'Author3'],
  comments:[
    {
      name:'name 1',
      comment:'comment 1'
    },
    {
      name:'name 2',
      comment:'comment 2'
    },
    {
      name:'name 3',
      comment:'comment 3'
    }
  ]
});
```

And Template:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>{{body}}</p>
<p>
  <strong>Authors:</strong>
  {{#each authors}}
    {{this}},
  {{/each}}
</p>
<h4>Comments</h4>
<ul>
{{#each comments as c}}
  <li><strong>{{name}}</strong> - {{comment}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

And it has been generating this output:

> ```
> My Blog Post
>
> Body of the post
>
> Authors: <my-app@controller:post::ember424>, <my-app@controller:post::ember424>, <my-app@controller:post::ember424>,
>
> Comments
>
>  -
>  -
>  -
> ```

I double check everything and it is identical to the demo I am seem, I also try to use {{#each comments as |c|}}, {{each authors as author}} {{this.author}}, try to use {{c.name}}, also try {{this.name}}, {{this.c.name}}

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your template file to this:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>{{body}}</p>
<p>
  <strong>Authors:</strong>
  {{#each authors as |author|}}
    {{author}},
  {{/each}}
</p>
<h4>Comments</h4>
<ul>
{{#each comments as |c|}}
  <li><strong>{{c.name}}</strong> - {{c.comment}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan_C, I had update to {{#each comments as |c|}} but I didn't use the {{c.name}} that did the trick

Comment: @lcaro, glad it helped! :)